# Validation / Error Messages in ASP.Net MVC 2 View Unrelated to a Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation

What pattern can I use to display errors on an MVC 2 view that are not related to a single property?

For example, when I call a web service to process form data, the web service may return an error or throw an exception.  I would like to display a user-friendly version of that error, but have no logical means to relate the error to any given property of the model.

UPDATE:

Trying to use this code as suggested, but no summary message is displayed:

MyPage.spark:

```
Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Oopps it didn't work.");
```

Controller:

```
ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "My custom error message.");
// Also tried this: ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "My custom error message.");
return View();
```

UPDATE 2

What does this mean?

next to each field.

> Instead of always displaying all
>   validation errors, the
>   Html.ValidationSummary helper method
>   has a new option to display only
>   model-level errors. This enables
>   model-level errors to be displayed in
>   the validation summary and
>   field-specific errors to be displayed
>   next to each field.

Source: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc#_TOC3_14

**Specifically**, how does one add a model level error (as opposed to a field-specific error) to the model?

UPDATE 3:

I noticed this morning that `Html.ValidationSummary` is not displaying any errors at all, not even property errors.  Trying to sort out why.

Comment: This question is somewhat related to one that I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5697487/114029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adding a custom error to the `ModelState` object in conjunction with the `ValidationSummary()` extension method should do the trick. I use something like `"_FORM"` for the key... just so it won't conflict with any fields.

As far as patterns go, I have it setup so that my Business Logic Layer (called via services from the controller) will throw a custom exception if anything expected goes wrong that I want to display on the view. This custom exception contains a `Dictionary<string, string>` property that has any errors that I should add to `ModelState`.

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: I'm doing something like what you suggest.  Could you have a look at my updated post and let me know if you see a problem?