# What's the best way to localize non Data Annotation Errors with ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, localization, business-logic

With Data Annotations it's now easy to localize error messages using Resource.resx files like this for example:

```
public class Student
{
    . . .

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName ="Required",
     ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(StudentResources))]
    [StringLength(16)] 
    [Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(StudentResources))]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    . . .
}
```

Now, let's say I want to check if a Student has already made a Payment for a given month and year:

```
public bool CheckIfAlreadyPaid(Payment payment)
{
    return repository.GetPayments().Any(p => p.StudentId == payment.StudentId &&
                                        p.Month == payment.Month &&
                                        p.Year == payment.Year);
}
```

If he has already made the Payment, I'm doing the following in my Services layer:

```
if (CheckIfAlreadyPaid(payment))
{
    modelState.AddModelError("AlreadyPaid",
    Resources.Views.Payment.PaymentCreateResources.AlreadyPaid);
}
```

It works, but I don't fell confident about referencing the Resource file inside the Services layer.

Is there a standard or better way of localizing error messages that are not tied to model properties (Data Annotation) - errors that come from business logic rules? Should I still add these errors to the ModelStateDictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in a different way. The `Service` layer is used to check if the Payment was already made. In my `Controller` I add a validation error message to the ModelState object passing to it a localized string resource. Now I feel more comfortable with this approach.

Here's the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Performs validation of business logic...
/// </summary>
/// <param name="payment"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private bool ValidatePayment(Payment payment)
{
    if (paymentService.IsPaymentMade(payment))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("AlreadyPaid", Localization.AlreadyPaid);
    }

    return ModelState.IsValid;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To complement my answer, I just found today that [ValidationSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460343.aspx) `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` does exactly what I want:

> `Html.ValidationSummary` returns an unordered list (ul element)
>   of validation messages that are in the `ModelStateDictionary` object and optionally displays only model model-level errors.

I'm passing `true` and it will only display model-level errors (non data annotation errors) in the summary just at the top of the page. This is great but only if it would work... :)

I was facing a problem where my custom error messages not tied to model properties weren't appearing when I set `ValidationSummary(true)`. I then searched using Google and found this [post](http://markegilbert.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/making-sense-on-many-levels-asp-net-mvc-2-and-model-level-error-reporting/). I tried his solution but it didn't work. I then searched a little bit more and found this [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=lfPkn31fpNQC&lpg=PA203&ots=B_W6H7S1rj&dq=model%20level%20error%20%2b%20ValidationSummary%28true%29&pg=PA203#v=onepage&q=model%20level%20error%20%20%20ValidationSummary%28true%29&f=false) in Google Books (Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework by Steven Sanderson).

I tried what is described there passing an empty string as key (`string.Empty`) and it did the job.

```
if(paymentService.IsPaymentMade(payment))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Localization.PaymentAlreadyCreated);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I don't think that should be in the service layer.  It looks like it could either be put into a custom data validation attribute, or handled with some other approach at that level (using [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) might be a good option).  Either way, I think as long as the validation stays in the MVC app itself, you can be comfortable using resource files to store the messages.